React Navigation Warning: "The action 'NAVIGATE' was not handled by any navigator" During Auth Transitions
MAIN HOW TO RESOLVE THIS WARNING, AND IS THIS WARNING HARMFUL. IF YOUR NAVAGTION WORKS FINE.
My app navigates based on the user’s login state:
I know this warning coming beacuse of using ternary operator if user logged in or not .
If logged in, it navigates to the ProfileTicket screen.
If not logged in, it navigates to the Welcome screen.
The WARNING:
.......
When logging in or out, navigation works, but I get the following warning:
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Welcome"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'Welcome'?
If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator
.......
What I Tried:
Verified that screen names like "Welcome" and "ProfileTicket" match exactly.
Checked that the Firebase auth state is updating correctly.
Attempted to manually navigate using navigation.navigate("Welcome").
Set initialRouteName based on the user’s auth state.
Expected Behavior:
On logout, I expect the app to navigate to the Welcome screen without errors.
On login, it should smoothly transition from the Welcome screen to the ProfileTicket screen.
The Problem:
The app navigates correctly but still shows this warning. Is this something to be concerned about, or is it safe to ignore? How can I resolve this?
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, StatusBar, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './Network/Store';
import NetworkStatus from './components/NetworkStatus';
import Welcome from './Pages/Welcome';
import Login from './Pages/Login';
import NewTicket from './Pages/NewTicket';
import ProfileTicket from './Pages/ProfileTicket';
import ViewProfile from './Pages/ViewProfile';
import Otp from './Pages/Otp';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return () => subscriber(); // Unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return <ActivityIndicator />;

  const getUserData = (user) => {
    if (!user) return null;
    return {
      uid: user.uid,
      phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber
    };
  };

  const userData = getUserData(user);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={user ? "ProfileTicket" : "Welcome"}>
          {user ? (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="ProfileTicket"
                component={ProfileTicket}
                initialParams={{ user: userData }}
                options={{ headerLeft: () => <View></View> }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen name="ViewProfile" component={ViewProfile} />
              <Stack.Screen name="NewTicket" component={NewTicket} />
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Otp" component={Otp} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            </>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
        <NetworkStatus />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;


Are you calling navigate(“Welcome”) on logout?
